# Get Network Computer Names

Tags: java

I'm looking for a better way to get the computer names in my LAN network with Java.  I have tried:

```
byte[] ip = {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)178,(byte)1};
    for(int i=1;i<255;i++)
    {
        ip[3] = (byte)i;
        try
        {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            String s = addr.getHostName();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

... but it's too slow.  Is there any other way?

I am on Windows.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: How slow is slow? How fast do you want it?

Comment: reverse dns is inherently slow. not all IPs have reverse mappings, and generally speaking, if one ip in a block has no reverse, then it's likely the rest won't have any either.

Comment: Threading should get you pretty far in speeding this up, but otherwise your performance is at the mercy of your DNS server and network

Comment: I'd think there'd be some trick or hack to bypass actually hitting every possible IP address (go to the router that you're connected to and retrieve the info).  Maybe not with Java though.

Comment: i was thinking of the filechooser dialog, how does it get the computer names in the network? it is pretty fast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can increase speed by using multiple threads.

Have each thread execute one or more of the iterations of your 'try' block.

Comment: Thanks 'll give that a try

Comment: @user1380282 Great! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are wondering, here's what i've come up with:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class nameLookup implements Runnable
{
    byte[] ip;
    String[] names;
    int index;
    public nameLookup(byte[] ip,int index,String[] names)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.names = names;
        this.index = index;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            names[index]= addr.getHostName();

        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static String[] lookUp()
    {
        byte[] ip = {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)178,(byte)1};
        String[] names = new String[254];
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[254];

        for(int i=0;i<254;i++)
        {
            ip[3] = (byte)(i+1);
            threads[i] = new Thread(new nameLookup(ip,i,names));
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<254;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                threads[i].join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

I still wish it was faster, but now it is at least acceptable.